# a question about determining number of codewords of specific weight

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, coding-theory

[image]

Here to determine the number of solutions to the diagonal equation, we need to find number of codewords of weight $i$, i.e. $A_i$, in a formula. But here to calculate those $A_i$, I found no formula for the weight distribution of the linear cyclic codes. In this case the principal ideal ring over which the code is formed is $\mathbb{F}_2[x]/\langle x^9-1\rangle$. But how to calculate the $A_i$'s I don't get here. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A_0=1$ is obvious. The rest is due to the special structure of $G$.

Clearly no linear combination of the rows of $G$ will yield a weight 1 codeword.

Since the rows $g_i$ of $G$ have weight 2, there are 6 codewords of weight 2. Also note that $g_i\oplus g_{i+3}$ has weight 2 due to cancellation, and there are 3 choices of such $i$, namely $i=1,2,3.$ This means $A_2=9.$

Clearly one cannot get weight 3 by linear combinationrs of the rows of $G$ either.

As for $A_4,$ take all pairs of rows $g_i,g_j$ subject to $i\neq j  \pmod 3.$

No codeword of weight 5 can be produced from linear combinations of these rows.

As for $A_6$ I didn't check carefully but taking linear combinations of all triples of rows $g_i,g_j,g_k$ subject to 
$$i\neq j  \pmod 3\quad i \neq k \pmod 3 \quad j\neq k \pmod 3$$
should work.

Then observe $1+9+27+27=64=2^6,$ so there are no more codewords by dimension arguments.

Comment: Do you have any formula that uses number theoretic argument for this purpose? Because this process gets a bit painful (and lengthy also) if $i$ takes little large values.

Comment: This is an unsolved problem in general. It is known for some specific code families such as Reed-Muller, Reed-Solomon, MDS codes. As well as some specific codes such as Golay.